# Will temporary arrays in subroutines be reallocated on each call?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

If I have a loop like

```
do i = 1,much
  call computations(input(i,:),output(i,:))
enddo
```

and

```
subroutine computations(inn,outt)
real, intent(in) :: inn(:)
real, intent(out) :: outt(:)
real :: temp(size(inn))
...
end subroutine
```

will the array `temp` be allocated and deallocated on each call? We can assume that the size of `input` and `output` are not changing. If I did not have a subroutine but rather inline code in the loop, then this array would have to be defined higher up, and would not be reallocated on each loop iteration. Will the compiler realize this? Does it depend on optimization level/compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the array will be allocated on each call. However, if it is allocated on the stack, the allocation is essentially free (just updating the stack pointer). One can never be sure about compiler optimizations unless you specify the compiler and the version, but I am not aware of any optimization like this, that would be very complicated. And also we would have to know the size of the array and whether the compiler allocates on the stack or on the heap.

If the subroutine is internal, you can allocate the array higher up. You can also allocate it higher up and pass it as an argument. But only do that if it really brings anything. If it is a rather small stack array, it would not achieve much.

Comment: When the size is fixed I have tried adding the `save` attribute to such arrays, which in my experience can improve performance, for this reason I think.

Comment: Might not the compiler inline the routine? In that case the allocation should exit the loop.

Comment: The compiler do anything it wants. You did not show where the subroutine is placed. Anything can happen. If it uses stack allocaation, it does not matter, stack allocation is free.